# Postgres run multithreaded call from function

Tags: postgresql

I need to run one stored function from another in PostgreSQL server, but I need to run inner function in 4 threads to reduce in execution time.
I can do that by make 4 threaded calls from backend, but it will more complex than call inside PostgeSQL server.
I'm using plpgsql language.

I'd like to make something like following

```
create or replace function abc(some_data integer)
returns integer
language plpgsql
as $$
declare
  intermediate_data some_my_type;
  is_done boolean;
  result integer;
begin
  intermediate_data := result_of_synchronous_call(some_data);

  async perform asinchronous_call(intermediate_data.part1);
  async perform asinchronous_call(intermediate_data.part2);
  async perform asinchronous_call(intermediate_data.part3);
  async perform asinchronous_call(intermediate_data.part4);

  SELECT count(*) = 4 INTO is_done FROM results;
  while not is_done loop
    SELECT pg_sleep(10);
    SELECT count(*) = 4 INTO is_done FROM results;
  end loop;
  
  SELECT sum(result_field) INTO result FROM results;
  return result;
end;
$$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no pretty way to do this. The best I can think of is to use the [dblink](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dblink.html) extension and use `dblink_send_query` to send a query. Completion status can be checked with `dblink_is_busy`, and the results are ultimately collected with `dblink_get_result`.

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion is exactly I searched for!